# Rails: What's the difference between ActiveRecord::Base.transaction and MyClass.transaction?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm looking at the docs here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html

One example it gives is:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  david.withdrawal(100)
  mary.deposit(100)
end
```

Another example in the docs is:

```
Account.transaction do
  balance.save!
  account.save!
end
```

What's the difference between the `Base`'s method and the `Account`'s method?

Comment: The account model inherits from **ActiveRecord::Base** so both are actually the same methods.

Comment: @PradoshGaonkar Put that as an answer and I'll accept!

Comment: `Account` inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base` obviously.  So you're calling a class method `transaction` on `Account` by `Account.transaction`.  If it's defined, this will be used, if not, `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction` is called; in this case, the two are equivalent.  But I wonder under what circumstances you want to define a model specific transaction handling code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The account model inherits from ActiveRecord::Base so both are actually the same methods.

Comment: I have two transaction blocks

`User.transaction do User.find(1).destroy raise end` and 
`ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do User.find(1).destroy raise end` First one is rollbacking the deletion but the second one is not!

Comment: Little late here. @HarshwardhanRathore both blocks are doing rolling back for me. Both transaction methods are internally exactly same .